# Как считать данные из файла в модель данных?

Tags: java, android, text, filestream

Каждые 10 строк в файле повторяется структура данных, например:

```
name1
name2
name3
.....
name10

name1
name2
name3
.....
name10
```

Необходимо считать данные в модель. Я читаю так:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Data data= new Data();
        String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, " ");
            for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
                myApplication.setDataValue1(strings[0].trim);
                myApplication.setDataValue2(strings[1].trim);
                myApplication.setDataValue3(strings[2].trim);
                ...
            }
        data.setData(myApplication.getDataValue);
        }
        br.close();
    }
catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Но таким образом считывается совсем не то, что мне бы хотелось. В чём ошибка?

Comment: Если у вас 10 элементов name, то цикл должен быть или до 10 или от 1 до 11. Но никак не от 0 до 11.

Comment: А какую ошибку выдает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне кажется следующая строка лишняя.

```
String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, " ");
```

Ведь ваш файл считывается построчно. И в каждой `line` будет соответствующее `name`.

Попробуйте сделать что-то вроде:

```
int j = 0;
String [] strings = new String [11];

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    strings[j % 11] = line;
    j++;
    if (j % 11 == 0) {
        myApplication.setDataValue1(strings[0].trim);
        myApplication.setDataValue2(strings[1].trim);
        ...
        myApplication.setDataValue2(strings[9].trim);
        data.setData(myApplication.getDataValue());
    }
}
```

Хотя смысл последней команды мне непонятен (getDataValue - это что метод или поле).

Подозреваю, что мое решение не совсем в точку, но если вы предоставите больше информации - класс `myApplication`, `Data`, то можно будет помочь вам более точно.

Comment: getDataValue это геттер в поле Data, класс Data содержит следующие данные :
private String value1
private String value2
private String value3
..
Класс myApplication  -  в нем создан экземпляр класса Data, и создан геттер.

Comment: @Сергей Непонятно, как используются множество наборов данных name1, ..., name10. Они назначаются одному и тому же экземпляру myApplication? Что возвращает myApplication.getDataValue(). Приведите, пожалуйста в вопросе методы setDataValuei() getDataValue, setData(). Лучше привести целые классы, исключая лишь то, что совсем не относится к делу.

Comment: @Сергей Ответ исправлен - учтена одна пустая строчка между блоками в файле (10 заменено на 11), но из массива используются только первые 10 элементов.

Comment: спасибо, использовал вашу идею, да был не прав что использовал ссылку на уже созданную ссылку, и ваш вариант очень пригодился.

Answer (score 1):

1. Попробуйте сначала прочитать весь файл в одну строку.
2. Потом порезать строку на массив с разделителем в два переноса строки `\n\n`
3. Теперь осталось порезать каждую ячейку массива по разделителю в один перенос строки `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю своего исходничка:

```
try {
    // Конструкция, авто закрытие файла
    try(FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("test")){
        // Если в файле байтов хотя бы 1
        if(file.available() > 0){ 
            // Буфер, первоначальное количество 10 байт
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(10); 
                int a = -1;
                while(true){
                    a = file.read();  // Читаем поток
                    // -1 конец (всё, в файле ничего нету)
                    if(a == -1) break;
                    // 10 это \n
                    if(a == 10){
                        // Пишу считанную строку, что с ней еще делать...
                        System.out.println(out.toString());

                        out.reset(); // Чистим буфер
                        continue;
                    }
                    out.write(a); // Пишем считанный байт в буфер
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

P.S. `(Buffered)Reader` не советую: памяти скушает очень много (а если файл огромный, то еще больше). Если надо - могу сделать работу trim на лету, не используя trim().